# Documentum cmis restful integration with android?

Tags: rest, cmis, documentum, opencmis, cmis-workbench

I want to implement documentum cmis restful api with android. So where i can get all the materialsand learn about it . I am very new to this and want to understand documentum and cmis restful api. So that i can integrate with android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your starting point for CMIS should be the CMIS specification.

http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/CMIS-v1.1.html

Then the implementation of CMIS specification in Chemistry project
https://chemistry.apache.org/

There is a specific Android client for CMIS which can be used in Android Apps.
https://chemistry.apache.org/java/download.html

A useful post here
https://superuser.com/questions/1044729/how-to-enable-cmis-on-documentum/1044787

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [OpenCMIS](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html) library on Android.

I is the standard way to interact with CMIS repositories (including Documentum) in the Java world.

The official documentation has very useful samples that will get you started quickly: https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/create-session/index.html