# Cmis connectivity to Documentum

Tags: alfresco, cmis, documentum, opencmis, alfresco-enterprise

Is there any guidelines to connect to Documentum via Java code. My whole scenario is to copy files from Documentum to Alfresco 5.2 using Java code (need to copy all metadata too)

Comment: You are migrating from Documentum to Alfresco?

Comment: Ya I want to do it but I am figuring out how to do it . As using CMIS I can easily connect to Alfresco and get it's session.

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158324/documentum-cmis-restful-integration-with-android

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed, CMIS is the best way to do this.

- Documentum implements CMIS relatively well, you will be able to extract data and metadata from all documents.
- Alfresco implements CMIS greatly, you will be able to create the documents using the data and metadata from Documentum.

Obviously, your Java code will need to have a mapping telling it how to match metadata between the two servers.